# Allowing many users to view stale BigQuery data query results concurrently

Tags: google-bigquery

If I have a BigQuery dataset with data that I would like to make available to 1000 people (where each of these people would only be allowed to view their subset of the data, and is OK to view a 24hr stale version of their data), how can I do this without exceeding the 50 concurrent queries limit?

In the BigQuery documentation there's mention of 50 concurrent queries being permitted which give on-the-spot accurate data, which I would surpass if I needed them to all be able to view on-the-spot accurate data - which I don't.

In the documentation there is mention of Batch jobs being permitted and saving of results into destination tables which I'm hoping would somehow allow a reliable solution for my scenario, but am having difficulty finding information on how reliably or frequently those batch jobs can be expected to run, and whether or not someone querying results that exist in those destination tables is in itself counting towards the 50 concurrent users limit.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried [contacting Cloud sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/)? They can help you configure your project appropriately for the number of users that you expect. 50 concurrent queries is the default, but there are plenty of large projects that support many more users than that.

Comment: Try http://redash.io/ (open source dashboards) which can have BigQuery as the backend

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of your situation and depending on how much data is in the output, I would suggest putting your own cache in front of BigQuery.

This sounds kind of like a dashboading/reporting solution, so I assume there is a large amount of data going in and a relatively small amount coming out (per-user).

Run one query per day with a batch script to generate your output (grouped by user) and then export it to GCS. You can then break it up into multiple flat files (or just read it into memory on your frontend). Each user hits your frontend, you determine which part of the output to serve up to them and respond.

This should be relatively cheap if you can work off the cached data and it is small enough that handling the BigQuery output isn't too much additional processing.

Google Cloud Functions might be an easy way to handle this, if you don't want the extra work of setting up a new VM to host your frontend.